# 404 error on remote appengine-go static file while local deploy works

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm facing a problem where a static file is showing up correctly on the local machine via dev_appserver.py but once uploaded to the server it doesn't show and gives me a 404 error.

The partial directory file structre is:

```
- static/
    articles.html
    images/*.png
```

The partial app.yaml file is:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

- url: /(articles\.html)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/*.html
```

I then to access this via the http url appname.appspot.com/articles.html.

I downloaded the code after I put it on the appengine server to ensure that articles.html has actually been uploaded in the said directory, and it has.  So the exact same file structre locally and on the server, but it gives a 404 on the server and works locally.  I have the latest versions of the appengine.  Any help on what I could be doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Sathish

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this up for completeness ... I went back and tried various reasonable combinations again and found that this config works:

```
- url: /(articles)\.html
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/.*.html
```

It is ridiculous of me to make the claim now, but I remember attempting a regex for the "upload" entry earlier and it hadn't worked.  So, I don't clearly know the issue, however, my best guess is that dev_appserver.py is probably taking some shortcuts to serve static files and not behaving exactly like the appengine would.  I shall raise an issue on that and see if there is any resolution or clarification.